# React: If I import a useState value from hook, will the component be re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs

`Test` and `Test2` component import useState value `test` from custom hook(`useTest.ts`).
I thought both components will be re-rendered when I click "clicked me" because imported useState value `test` will be updated.
But actually, only `Test` component is re-rendered. Can anyone explain the reason for me ...?

App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from './Test';
import { Test2 } from './Test2';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Test />
      <Test2 />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.tsx

```js
import { useTest } from "./hooks/useTest";

export const Test = () => {
  console.log("Test1 is rendered");

  const {test, testSet, increment} = useTest();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test1</h1>
      <h2>{test}</h2>
      <h2>{testSet}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => {increment()}}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Test2.tsx

```js
import { useTest } from "./hooks/useTest";

export const Test2 = () => {
  console.log("Test2 is rendered");
  const {test, testSet} = useTest();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test2</h1>
      <h2>{test}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

useTest.ts

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export const useTest = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(["orange", "apple", "banana"]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const testSet = new Set(test);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
    setTest(pre => [...pre, `grape${count}`])
    // setTest(newTest);
  };

  return { test, testSet, increment}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each component has its own state. The `useTest` hook creates state in each component that uses it; there's no connection between those states.

If you want to share state between components, you need to move the state into their parent component, and then pass it down as properties.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. also, you can use context to share state between the 2 components.

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have been doing this same thing https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state.

To summarize, if I want to share state between components, I need

- to move the state into their parent component

- to use context 

- to use Recoil and so on

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are used to share the stateful logic between multiple components. There is a great explanation on the [react docs](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#custom-hooks-let-you-share-stateful-logic-not-state-itself).

> Custom Hooks let you share stateful logic but not state itself. Each call to a Hook is completely independent from every other call to the same Hook.

If you want your components to be re-rendered when the state value changes, you can use the [context api](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

Answer (score 0):

The reason only `Test` is re-rendered is due to the specific state dependencies each component has. `Test` depends on `testSet`, which changes on each render, triggering a re-render. `Test2` only depends on `test`, which doesn't change in a way that requires `Test2` to re-render.